# How to enable partial searches for all fields?

Tags: python, django, filter

Imagine I ahve the following filters.py:

```
class ActionFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Action
        fields = "__all__"
```

Now, I want to enable partial searches for Charfield fields in my model. How can this be enabled?

EDIT

```
class ActionFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    name = django_filters.CharFilter(field_name = 'name', lookup_expr='icontains')
    description = django_filters.CharFilter(field_name = 'description', lookup_expr='icontains')
    class Meta:
        model = Action
        fields = "__all__"
```

HTML:

```
        <div class="card-body">
            {% load django_tables2 %}
            {% render_table table %}
            {% if table.filter %}
                <form action="" method="get" class="form form-inline">
                    {% bootstrap_form table.filter.form layout='inline' %}
                    {% bootstrap_button 'filter' %}
                </form>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

tables.py
import django_tables2 as tables

```
from .models import Action, ControlTest
from .filters import ActionFilter

class actionTable(tables.Table):
    action_report = tables.Column(accessor='report.type')
    title_report = tables.Column(accessor='report.name')
    date_report = tables.Column(accessor='report.date')
    business_unit = tables.Column(accessor='bu.name')
    wallet_holder = tables.Column(accessor='control.bu')
    owner = tables.Column(accessor='owner')
    title_finding = tables.Column(accessor='actionr')
    description_finding = tables.Column(accessor='actionr.description')
    

    class Meta:
        Action.filter = ActionFilter
        model = Action
        fields = ('id', 'action_report', 'title_report', 'date_report', 'due_date','priority','business_unit', 'wallet_holder', 'owner', 'delegate', 'reviewer1', 'reviewer2', 'title_finding', 'description_finding','Action_Comments',
        'name', 'description', 'ControlID', 'ReportID', 'BUid', 'UserID_as_ActionOwner', 'UserID_as_ActionOwner', 'UserID_as_Actionreviewer', 'Priority',
        'status', 'Action_History', 'Review_Comments', 'documentation', 'referencenumber')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question wasn't quite clear to me (i.e. what you actually meant by partial).

But I think you meant if the field contains some of the text you filter for i.e. "The" in a qs whose title is "This is the greatest example". If that's what you are looking for then, you need to use `i__contains`.

`title = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains',field_name='title')`

Comment: Thank you for your comment! What if the fields I want to specify are of the __all__ type in Meta? Can I specify an icontains for them?

Comment: can you please explain what do you mean by all

Comment: Yes ofcourse. I have the following code in html (see edit), when I add the name = django_filters.CharFilter it gets me the  name contains tag in the front end. So you would think it would work: it does ignore case sensitivity now however no partial search. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hmm, I think you can't provide fields as "__all__" maybe try adding fields in an array like so ```fields=['name','description']```, tell me if it works.